# Why adding a dependency to slf4j-log4j12 does not make slf4j work properly?

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j

I have a project using slf4j. So I need to provide an underlying framework.
I wanted to use log4j, so I specified the following dependency in my `pom.xml`, as specified [here](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#projectDep) :

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.0-beta2</version>
</dependency>
```

But I still have the following error message :

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

which shouldn't appear anymore, according to [this](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder).

If I change the dependency to this one, found on the net, it works :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Does anyone have an explanation ?

Comment: It seems that there is an issue with the beta build you've been trying to use. Why don't you stick with the release version?

Comment: You're right : it works ! I simply used the piece of code from slf4j documentation, without thinking about the verion. But it was really simple. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue simply came from using a beta version of slf4j. Specifying a dependency to a stable version makes it work correctly :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```